# How to send and receive long data HC-05

Tags: esp8266

I have ESP8266 with HC-05  Bluetooth module .

I needed to  send large data from ESP8266 to my Android app(wireless).

Firstly Both HC-05 and ESP connected together and write a code in ESP8266(As below).

Here i am sent a small data from ESP8266  to Android app(like "S2 Terminal for Bluetooth").

How can i send a structure data(contains multiple informations)  from ESP8266?
please give me some examples

Thanks.

```css
#include "BluetoothSerial.h" //Header File for Serial Bluetooth, will be added by default into Arduino

BluetoothSerial ESP_BT; //Object for Bluetooth

int incoming;
int LED_BUILTIN = 2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //Start Serial monitor in 9600
  ESP_BT.begin("ESP32_LED_Control"); //Name of your Bluetooth Signal
  Serial.println("Bluetooth Device is Ready to Pair");

  pinMode (LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);//Specify that LED pin is output
}

void loop() {
 
  if (ESP_BT.available()) //Check if we receive anything from Bluetooth
  {
    incoming = ESP_BT.read(); //Read what we recevive
    Serial.print("Received:"); Serial.println(incoming);

    if (incoming == 49)
        {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        ESP_BT.println("LED turned ON");
        }
       
    if (incoming == 48)
        {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        ESP_BT.println("LED turned OFF");
        }     
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the data as a char (byte) array then send it with the same command you are using to send your string "S2 terminal for Bluetooth".

So currently you're doing something like Serial.write("S2 terminal for Bluetooth");

You can send multiple pieces of information using a (packed) struct. Packed means there are no extra bytes inserted by the compiler for alignment.

```
typedef struct {
    int data_num_a;
    int data_num_b;
    char[32] data_str_c;
    char[32] data_str_d;
} __attribute__((__packed__))data_msg_t;
```

So here is how you would send data using this:

```
data_msg_t my_message;
my_message.data_num_a = 1234;
my_message.data_num_b = 5678;
memcpy(my_message.data_str_c, "String of up to 32 characters", 32);
memcpy(my_message.data_str_d, "other string", 32);

Serial.write((char*)&my_message, sizeof(my_message));
```